# Is DataCache.Increment available with WindowsAzure shared caching?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-caching, shared-cache

I'm trying to use WindowsAzure shared cache and the Increment operator of the DataCache class documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj160018.aspx.

The Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll I'm using came from the 1.7 nuget package for caching http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Caching but I cannot find the increment method in that assembly.

Is the Increment method available in Azure and if it is what dll should I reference to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it and found this function is added into Windows Azure Cache (Preview) - with Dedicated or co-located. So if you decided to use Windows Azure Cache Preview with your Web or Worker Role either in dedicated or co-located mode, you sure can use this functionality. If you want to know the difference between Windows Azure Shared Cache and Windows Azure Caching (Preview) please take a look at my blog: [Difference between Windows Azure Cache(Preview) and Windows Azure Shared Cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/18/difference-between-windows-azure-cache-preview-and-windows-azure-share-cache.aspx)

This function is not available with WindowsAzure shared cache.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere? I didn't see it in the main "differences" page on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185678

Comment: As of now it is not documented "as such" however Windows Azure Cache (preview) is still in preview, so the documentation will subject to improve. I will see if I can get something documented on this regard.